# How to change Django variables inside templates

Tags: django, templates, variables, tags

I need to change the Django variables from my templates.
for example, I have a variable named `{{ fof_list.3.view_count}}` and every time I click in an specific button, i need to increase this variable, like:

```
{{ fof_list.3.view_count}} += 1;
```

Is that possible? How to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template language won't let you do that.  You'll need to setup an ajax request that fires everytime the button is pressed and increments the view count.

Here's example of how you'd hook that all up (completely untested)

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="increase-count-link">Increment View Count</a>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#increase-count-linkn').click(function() {
    $.ajax('/list/5/incrementcount/');
});
```

View:

```
def incrementcount(request, list_id):
    list = List.objects.get(id=list_id)
    list.view_count += 1
    list.save()

    return http.HttpResponse('View count incremented successfully')
```

Comment: alright, unfortunately I'm new at website development so I've no idea on how to use ajax to do that. Any suggestions on where to study from?